# Is it possible to "POST" through a link (<a href>)

Tags: php, html

I'd like to send a post value depending on what link was pressed. Is it possible to do this without a button?

This is what i got (not working =)

**HTML**

```
<a href="time.html.php" id="select_month" name="select_month" value="01" action="post">Jan</a>
```

**PHP**

```
$selected_month = $_POST['select_month'];
```

Comment: @Hudixt: Long answer: Asynchronous Javascript and XML?

Comment: I thought so,,, but i was qurious on the html. Jquery with AJAX is my second chooise

Comment: Intercept the click event via JavaScript,  submit the data as needed (perhaps via AJAX) and then redirect the browser to the intended destination.

Comment: No you cannot do a post with an anchor, without using JS... Only a form.

Comment: That will not work because **value** and **action** attributes are not supported in <a> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST, by definition, can only happen through an HTML `<form>` tag. An anchor `<a>` tag is, also by definition, a GET operation only. Javascript is also capable of POST via AJAX (I would highly suggest a framework like [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and their [post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/))

```
<script>
     function postExample() {
         $.post('/your/url/here', {"postfield1":"val1"}, function(resp) {
             //Do something with the AJAX response
         });
     }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="postExample(); return false;">Your Link here</a>
```

What this does is we're more or less hijacking the anchor tag to use it as a vehicle to capture the click event. The `#` is our href placeholder because it won't actually send the browser to a new URL. When the click is performed, our JS function is called and then we `return false;` to prevent the anchor from being successful (i.e. sending the browser to another page). If the anchor contained a real URL and were successful, there's no guarantee the asynchronous POST would ever fire.

Comment: Perfect answear. But below is a very short code with GET option. Why is that not good enough?

Comment: If you're working with simple values and anchors only, then yes `$_GET` is the preferred answer because that's how `<a href>` naturally works. But your title stated you wanted to avoid that and use only POST with an anchor tag

Comment: Thank you. Im not a very good programmer. The function is only there for filtering a list of values. So i guess GET can work good enough for me this time. But i will give your answear the "right" status, for my POST question.

Answer (score 1):

USE $_GET,

```
<a href="time.html.php?month=01">Jan</a>
```

then use php:

```
$_GET['month'];
```

Comment: This option is good because of the small code! Why did it get down voted?

Comment: @d00rman Maybe because that's not actually what you asked for? Look at the title of your question (and no, that's not my downvote)

Comment: @Machavity ok, thanks. Of course i asked for a POST function. But i can really use a GET, if nobody tell me difrent. Creativy is just as welcome like straight forward answears.

Comment: @Machavity *Is it possible to “POST” through a link (<a href>)* "POST"ing **through a link** would be a GET request not a POST fyi

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.post`:

```
<a onclick="$.post('example.php', {'key':'value'});return false;" href="#">link<a/>
```